# highest value path in a 2D list python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, max, path-finding

okay so I have this problem I have a 2d grid and a player starts in the middle I have to find the highest value path to one of the corners I can but it can't go backwards like this you can only move up down left and right not diagonally

```
[[0,1,2,4,5],
[5,4,8,8,2],
[5,8,x,1,4],
[7,4,1,2,8],
[4,4,5,9,2]]
```

if you move up it becomes

```
[[0,1,2,4,5],
[5,4,x,8,2]]
```

and you now have a value of 8 any help would be appreciated I'm really struggling with this and its due soon

this is what i have so far building being the data type with room a 2d grid of ints and v being the value so far

```
    def LT(building,x,y,v):
    print(x,y,v)
    print(building.rooms[x][y].food)
    r=0
    if(not(x==0 and y ==0)):
        if(x-1>=0 and y-1>=0):
            if(building.rooms[x-1][y].food>building.rooms[x][y-1].food):
                return v + LT(building,x-1, y, v+building.rooms[x-1][y].food)
            else:
                return v + LT(building, x - 1, y, v + building.rooms[x][y-1].food)
        elif(not(x-1>=0)):
            return v + LT(building, x, y-1, v + building.rooms[x - 1][y].food)

        elif (not (y - 1 >= 0)):
            return v + LT(building, x-1, y , v + building.rooms[x - 1][y].food)

    return v
```

this is what I have at the moment for the top left corner but its returning a very high number and i cant get to to work

Comment: Path to where ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner to the corners have to find the one with the highest value

Comment: N,S,W,E  or  N,NW,W,SW,S,SE,E,NE ?  - add to question please.

Comment: N,S,W,E will do

Comment: Do you need to find the optimal way overall (you are able to see the full data and can explore w/o moving) or do you only see the possible walking directions and have to decide based on that ?

Comment: optimal way overall was just showing how you cant move backwards